# Method not found when dynamically loading a dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a C# .net 3.5 application.

I have an exe 'MainApp' which references a dll 'CommonDll'

The CommonDll dynamically loads another dll 'LoadedDll' and invokes dynamically a method called func().

The 'LoadedDll' references the 'CommonDll'

in the 'CommonDll' there is a method foo()   which the func() is calling.

```
    func()
    {
        foo();
    }
```

So, what we have so far:

MainApp *==>* CommonDll *==Dynamicly==>* LoadedDll

LoadedDll ==> CommonDll.

everything worked just fine, until I changed the method foo() to get a boolean argument: foo(bool val); and cheanged also the func() in 'LoadedDll' to

```
func()
{
foo(true);
}
```

I have the MainApp(references the old CommonDll) in version 1.0, and the LoadedDll(references the new CommonDll) in version 1.1

For some reason I get a "MethodNotFound Excepion" on the method foo saying it cannot find foo that gets a boolean argument.

Why is this happening? The LoadedDll is using a static reference to the updated CommonDll, so why it can't find that method?

Also, the exception doesn't saying that it cannot find the 'func()' method which is loaded dynamically, but it says that it cannot find the foo method.

**EDIT:**

I looked for the dll in the GAC but it is not there, is there another reason why an old dll that is already in the memory will be loaded instead of the new one?

Comment: I take it your using reflection to invoke these? If you are, have you passed the parameter object array to the invoke method?

Comment: Try to rebuild the application.

Comment: And check that you don't have a copy of either `LoadedDLL` or `CommonDLL` in your GAC...

Comment: This all seems really round the houses. Can you not re-factor the code out into another assembly to avoid the circular reference entirely?

Comment: @RB, if the Commondll has a different strong name will it be enough in order to make sure that the loaded dll will use the newer version?

Comment: @RB can my dll be in the GAC without me explictly puting it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for the issue.

there was some external code which cahnged the dll version to a constant value and therefore the strong name was the same.

buttom line: if you are load a dll and then you try to load another dll with the same strong name, the first dll will be used.

inorder to load 2 dlls with the same name they must have a different strong name.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me too. I deleted all extra dlls (their dependencies which have been previously loaded with my main exe) from the directory from where I was dynamically loading dlls. The reason in your answer is correct.